# How to fail the whole state.sls if one statement inside fails

Tags: salt-stack, configurationmanager

I'm just started with saltstack, so could anyone help with this question: How to fail the whole state.sls if one statement inside fails? Are requisites

> require/watch

suitable for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well. You can specify that a certain state will only be applied if another state is successfully applied as well. Like this:

```
vim:
  pkg.installed: []

/etc/vimrc:
  file.managed:
    - source: salt://edit/vimrc
    - require:
      - pkg: vim
```

The vimrc file will only be managed if the package vim is successfully is installed. It doesn't mater if vim was already installed or that it is a new installed package after this state. If the pkg: vim is successfully installed it will run the second state.

This is useful if you have a particularly state that might fail. You can add the `require` to all other states to make sure they will only be applied if this particularly state is successful.

To answer your question:
It's not possible to make all states inside the state.sls fail if one of them fails. You can work around this issue by running your state.sls with `salt '*' state.apply state test=True` to see what would happen. If one of the states would fail you can decide to not actually apply the state.

I hope this answers your question. If it's still unclear you might want to come up with an example :-)

Comment: Thanks :) This is what I need to be sure that things are going in the right way.

Answer (score 8):

You can use requisites and all **depending** states will fail as well as the required one.

An alternative is to *abort* the whole execution on a single state failure:

```
abort_on_failure_state_example:
  test.fail_without_changes:
    - failhard: True
```

No further state will be executed, even those from other included sls files.
I use that to ensure that some required grains are set before applying states, without having to check/require them on every state.

This is documented in https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/states/failhard.html